# Getting @Autowired error

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I'm getting an error whenever I'm using @Autowired annotation. The root error i get is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [jp.co.vmt.qt.C0002.C0002Dao] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

My interface is

```
/**
 *
 */
package jp.co.vmt.qt.C0002;

import java.util.List;

import jp.co.vmt.qt.model.TmtProject;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

/**
 * @author WINDOWS
 */
public interface C0002Dao extends JpaRepository<TmtProject, Long> {

  @Query("SELECT PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME FROM TmtProject")
  public List<TmtProject> getAllProjects();

}
```

And my implementing class is

```
/**
 *
 */
package jp.co.vmt.qt.C0002;

import java.util.List;

import jp.co.vmt.qt.model.TmtProject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 * @author WINDOWS
 */
@Repository
public class C0002Service implements C0002Dao {

  @Autowired
  private C0002Dao c0002Dao;

  /*
   * (non-Javadoc)
   * @see jp.co.vmt.qt.C0002.C0002Dao#getAllProjects()
   */
  @Override
  public List<TmtProject> getAllProjects() {

    return this.c0002Dao.getAllProjects();

  }

... other methods from extended interface

}
```

And here is where I used c0002Service

```
/**
 *
 */
package jp.co.vmt.qt.C0002;

import java.util.List;

import jp.co.vmt.qt.model.TmtProject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

/**
 * @author WINDOWS
 */
@Component
public class C0002Logic {

  @Autowired
  private C0002Dao c0002Service;

  public String getProjectList() throws Exception {

    List<TmtProject> projectList = this.c0002Service.getAllProjects();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(projectList);
    return jsonString;

  }

}
```

I have my C0002Logic autowired in my controller which is not shown here.
To my understanding, I created an interface (C0002Dao) and an implementing class (C0002Service) of that interface, which I marked with @Repository and I am autowiring the service to my Logic class (C0002Logic). However, I'm getting the error shown above. Any ideas on where I went wrong and how to solve them? Thanks

Comment: I added @Component to my DAO but it's still giving me the same error.

Comment: Why does your service implement the Spring Data JPA DAO? This makes no sense and shows you should start by reading the documentation (or at least one of the official tutorials)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I believe
In C0002Service,

```
@Autowired
private C0002Dao c0002Dao;
```

U r trying to inject to `C0002Dao` at the time qualifying bean (instance of `C0002Service`) is about to be registered.

Comment: What does that mean? Should I remove that part?

Comment: Yes. pls remove it.. you can't do DI for C0002Dao there.